# Which data type and collation for full UTF8 support in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I'm going to store data (mostly Wikipedia page titles) in a table, that can contain characters for which full UTF8 is needed.
The schema I'm using is

```
CREATE TABLE `en_brands` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
 `name_encoded` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `inserted` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

As you can see, `name` is only 191 characters long. When using larger values, then MySQL refuses the creation of `UNIQUE KEY name` because such keys can only be 767 bytes long. What are my questions:

- has `name_encoded` to be at least `TEXT` to fully store an URL-encoded (in PHP `rawurlencode`) UTF8 string? (I think an 255 byte long string could be represented by a 3060 character long URL in worst case - 255 chars x 4 bytes x 3 chars for encoded representation)
- does it matter which collation I use for `name_encoded` (I think not, because URL-encoded they should fit into `latin`)
- which data type and collation should I use for `name` to store at least 255 characters with full UTF8 support and to create an `UNIQUE KEY` nevertheless (I'd like to use a collation which allows native language sorting)

BTW: I'm using MySQL 5.6 Percona on Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question:

> has name_encoded to be at least TEXT to fully store an URL-encoded (in
>   PHP rawurlencode) UTF8 string?

for sure, an URL encoded UTF8 string can be up to 3060 characters long, so `TEXT` is required

> does it matter which collation I use for name_encoded (I think not,
>   because URL-encoded they should fit into latin)

URL encoded string fits into `ASCII`

> which data type and collation should I use for name to store at least
>   255 characters with full UTF8 support and to create an UNIQUE KEY
>   nevertheless

this is not possible, because of length restriction for text columns in `UNIQUE KEY`s

I'm checking for duplicates by executing a `SELECT` first, so there is no need for an `UNIQUE KEY`, but application has to ensure data integrity